Strobe 5 seconds, off ~50 seconds
Goal: strobe a couple of led for a few seconds, have off for about a minute, cycle/repeat.  I have several LM324, a couple 555, some 4017.  5v or 12v supply.  Can I use one op amp as a timer (90% off, 10% on) to turn on another op amp to flash a couple of led (or pulse small motor) for a few seconds, be off for a minute, repeat?  I see lots of links about astable and monostable circuits, but not with having a timer to trigger on/off.  Thanks for any thoughts, links, diagrams, direction.

They make addressable LEDs which can be digitally controlled from an Arduino or any cheap microcontroller. If you want precise timing this is probably the easiest solution.

It can be done without counter IC.
Just make two oscillators, one 5s on/50s off, and the second one for strobe.
The logic High of first one enables the second one (strobe).
